# Displaying Power options by account picture in Metro on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I somehow managed to get my home PC showing this next to my account picture:

[image: With Power Options]

This is really useful to have the power options readily available to me in the top right whenever you hit <kbd>Win</kbd>. My work machine just got upgraded to Windows 8.1 and I'm presented with this:

[image: Without!]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the same behavior between the two.

- **Home:** Windows 8.1 Professional
- **Work:** Windows 8.1 Enterprise (Business version of Professional if I remember correctly)

Comment: Your work machine may have had that disabled via Group Policy, have you checked for that? (`GPResult`, and/or go talk to the company's IT).

Comment: OP doesn't know how option got enabled... kinda hard to figure out if something you don't know how you enabled is disabled by Group Policy since you don't know what you enabled to check for a GP disabling. A rather Mind Warping entanglement there!  But don't worry!  Windows likely has a GP Disabling Option for _that_ too! (But we don't know the name!)

Comment: is your work device a tablet?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Work device is a desktop computer. @ techie007 Seeing as how I'm the second person on windows 8.1 in the company I doubt there's any explicit group policies for windows 8.1 features in play yet. We're kind of the guinea pigs for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this [Windows 8.1 Update KB2919355](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327) installed on your PC(For 32-bit OS). If not, then download this and install & reboot. For 64-bit OS [Download this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42335) and install.
 [More details from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1)

1.Open up the Registry editor(regedit.exe):
2.Navigate to the following:

> **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher**

3.Make sure the key name

> **Launcher_ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen**

is set to 1. That is 0x00000001 (1) the power button will be shown. If it is 0 then it'll be removed.

If **Launcher** key doesn't exist or if you dont want to edit registry manually, then type the following in *Notepad* and save it as **fix.reg** and double-click and allow to merge it and reboot.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher]
>   "Launcher_ShowPowerButtonOnStartScreen"=dword:00000001

Restart to see the power button near the profile picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately after applying the registry value and rebooting I still don't see this: [Picture for reference](http://i.imgur.com/vzOMCK1.png)

Comment: Also, this setting is not present on my home machine with the button.

Comment: Your PC don't have the [Windows 8.1 Update KB2919355](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42327) Download this and install & reboot. [More details from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1)

Comment: For 64-bit Windows 8.1 [Download this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42335)

Comment: @ArenB Have you tried my suggestions? I edited my answer recently.

Comment: Yes, Installed all 4 Security Updates at the link provided, registry key is active, rebooted and still no options in the Modern UI.